# Grid not getting updated

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I've the following code in my C#/WPF application. On clicking of Refrsh button, I invoke GetData method on the Viewmodel and try to reset the observable collection.
But data in grid is not getting updated. What am I doign wrong here?Is the Reset method logic in CustomObservableCollection class correct?

Thanks for your help.

ViewModel.cs:

```
private object _myLock = new object();
internal void GetData()
        {
            var data = ...//Get data from database

            lock (_myLock)
            {
                if (MyCollection != null )
                {
                    MyCollection.Reset(data);

                }
                else
                {
                    MyCollection = new CustomObservableCollection<Product>(data);
                }
            }
```

XAML:

```
    <Grid >
<.... ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" 
                                                        </Grid>

    <Button Click="RefreshGridButton_Click" Content="Refresh" />
```

CustomObservableCollection.cs

```
public class CustomObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private object _lock = new object();
    public CustomObservableCollection()
        : base()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }

    public CustomObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        : base(collection)
    {
    }


    public void Reset(IEnumerable<T> range)
    {
        if (range == this)
        {
            return;
        }
        lock (_lock)
        {
            this.Items.Clear();

            foreach (var item in range)
          {
                this.Items.Add(item);
            }

            this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
            this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, range, 0));


        }


    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your XAML code to the following one -

```
<... ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ... />
```

And actually I think it would be much easier to reinitialize your ObservableCollection instead of clearing and re-adding items again.